# How do i found the NumTrans column sum of data.table for Cust_map==1 and 2

Tags: r, data.table

```
> SS
   Cust_map Merch_Map_final TXN_MTH        SPND_CATGY NumTrans
1:        1            2412  201310 BUSINESS SERVICES        2
2:        1            2412  201401 BUSINESS SERVICES        3
3:        1            2412  201403 BUSINESS SERVICES        3
4:        1            2412  201406 BUSINESS SERVICES        3
5:        1            2412  201407 BUSINESS SERVICES        2
6:        2            2415  201310  GROCERY                 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'Cust_map' and get the `sum` of 'NumTrans'

```
SS[, .(NumTrans = sum(NumTrans)), by = Cust_map]
```